# PHP how to send array variables to Class function

Tags: php

I'm writing a code in PHP OOP and I'm trying to send $_POST data
 filtered by one Class function to another Class function that will add
 the data to database. Specifically login and password in registration
 form.

I have 3 Classes that will do that:

1. Is simple Class that handles connection to database (I think it is not necessary to put code here)
2. Is the Class that filters the coming $_POST-s:

   ```
   class Filter extends Dbconnect {
   protected $login;
   protected $haslo;

   public function regFilter() {
       if (isset($_POST))
           {
           foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
               {
               $filterVal = strip_tags($val);
               $filterVal = htmlspecialchars($filterVal);
               $filterVal = stripslashes($filterVal);
               $filterVal = str_replace("\\", "", $filterVal);
               $filter = array(
                   $key => $filterVal
               );
               foreach($filter as $key => $val)
                   {
                   echo "[$$key]";
                   echo "$val";
                   $
                       {
                       $key
                       } = $val;
                   }
               }

           return $filter = array(
               'login' => $login,
               'haslo' => $haslo
           );
           }
         else
           {
           echo "Proszę podać login i hasło!";
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Class that will get login and password and send it to DB:

   ```
   class Dbinsert extends regFilter{
   //protected $login;
   //protected $haslo;
   protected $query;
   protected $dbo;
   public function insert(){
   //$this->extract = extract($filter);
   //$this->login = $login;
   //$this->haslo = $haslo;
   $this->connect();
   $this->query = "INSERT INTO uzytkownik (id, nazwa, haslo) VALUES ('', :login, OLD_PASSWORD(:haslo))";  
   if(!$result = $this->connect()->prepare($this->query)){
   echo 'Zapytanie nie powiodło się';
   }
   else{
   $result->bindParam(':login', $login);
   $result->bindParam(':haslo', $haslo);
   $login = $_POST['login'];
   $haslo = $_POST['haslo'];
   $result->execute();
   }
   $dbo = null;
   }
   }
   ```

Now when I try to send data from form with objects:

```
    $rejestruj = new Dbinsert();
    $filtruj = $rejestruj->regFilter();
    var_dump($filtruj);
    $dodaj = $filtruj->insert();
```

I get the following result:

```
   [$login]login  
   [$haslo]password123  
   array(2) { ["login"]= string(5) "login" ["haslo"]= string(11) "password123" }  
   Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on array in `E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\register.php` on line 78
```

Which doesn't surprises me since:  login and haslo is returned from
 "foreach" loop in class Filter (which is just for testing)  "array(2)"
 is returned from "var_dump($filtruj);"(to check if it is actually
 working)   and error is returned since I send an array to Class
 Dbinsert - but in the function I put "extract" to get the variables.

How can I send just the variables from this filtered array to class
 Dbinsert?

Edit: As @Twinfriends suggested I corrected function insert in class Dbinsert to actually use prepared statement, thats why (for now) login and haslo variables are reffering to $_POST. Now I need answer to my question.

(First time posting, thanks for edit suggestions, also any advice is appreciated since I'm quite the beginner
 in PHP)

Comment: Please reformat your code properly so one can read it

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense. YOu try to bind variables to a query where you haven't any placeholders.

Comment: @Twinfriends you may be right since my method of working was writing procedural then converting it to OOP. But the query worked without filtering function.

Comment: @korni It may worked, but it didin't run as prepared statement. Your code was/is still really vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @Twinfriends how would you suggest to correct it? Or is this codes place in rubbish bin and I should start again?

Comment: @korni No, the query can be adapted quite fast. http://bobby-tables.com/php bobby-tables will help you. Simply visit this site and scroll down to the PDO section and change your code according to the tutorial there.

Comment: @Twinfriends I think I managed to do what you suggested. But now I need to get that filtered variables to the function.

Comment: @korni Can you edit your question and post your new code? So first of all I can take a look at your querys now and it will be much better to support you on your actual code rather than an older version.

Comment: @Twinfriends done. I edited it. It doesn't look pretty since I was doing "try and error" and for now I checked it works with $_POST.

Comment: @Twinfriends sorry to bother but did you come up with some solution?

Comment: @korni See the answer section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that it took so long to answer, I totally forgot your question. Well, lets take a look at your problem, hope to solve it.

I try to explain it as good as I can, so that you understand whats going on. First of all, lets look at your error message

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on array in
>   `E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\register.php` on line 78

Okay. Call to a function on array... lets have a look at how you actually call the function:

```
$rejestruj = new Dbinsert();
$filtruj = $rejestruj->regFilter();
var_dump($filtruj);
$dodaj = $filtruj->insert();
```

And exactly here is your error. You have to understand that you call methods on objects and pass your data to this methods, not to call the methods on your data. What do I mean with that?

`$rejestruj` is your Dbinsert object. You create it in your first line of code here. Then, you call the regFilter function on it. Still anything is fine. As you see, `var_dump` gives you the expected results. So the error has to be on your last lane of code. And indeed, you try to call the method `insert()` on your array. And that won't work, since your array don't know any method called `insert()`.

**The right call to the method would be (Not the final one!!!):**

`$dodaj = $rejestruj->insert();`

Now the method call should work. But in fact, it won't insert anything. Why? Because your `insert()` method try to bind the variables `$login` and `$haslo` - two variables the method don't know. So we need to pass the data in your method. To do that, you have to do the following changes:

**Method call:**

`$rejestruj->insert($filtruj); // $filtruj contains your array`

**And your Dbinsert should look like:**

```
class Dbinsert extends Dbconnect{
protected $query;
protected $dbo;

    public function insert($data){

        $this->connect();
        $this->query = "INSERT INTO uzytkownik (id, nazwa, haslo) VALUES ('', :login, OLD_PASSWORD(:haslo))";  
        if(!$result = $this->connect()->prepare($this->query)){
            echo 'Zapytanie nie powiodło się';
        }
        else {
            $result->bindParam(':login', $data["login"]);
            $result->bindParam(':haslo', $data["haslo"]);
            $result->execute();
        }
        $dbo = null;
    }
}
```

I hope your code works with this changes. So, while in my opinion the code should work now, I want to mention that there are many things you could improve. For example, you're not programming real "object-oriented" ... its more some pseudo OOP you're writing here. Some things are quite bad practice (could be done much easier). I don't want to dive to deep into details, since I don't know if you're interested in it. If you wish I can give you some more advises, but only if you wish.

Otherwise I really hope my answer help you. If the whole thing still doesn't work, please let me know so I can look at it again.

Have a nice day ;)

**Edit:**

Since it seems I haven't been clear enough, here the code how it should look like now:

```
$rejestruj = new Dbinsert();
$filtruj = $rejestruj->regFilter();
$dodaj = $rejestruj->insert($filtruj);
```

Comment: It works but I get a warning message:
"Warning: Missing argument 1 for Dbinsert::insert(), called in E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\register.php on line 78 and defined in E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\test_service.php on line 45", also I would really appriciate your help on the topic since I would like to get into PHP programming and learn to do it like it should be done. (Now I'm slowly going towards Laraver)

Comment: @korni Are you sure you call the method like `$rejestruj->insert($filtruj);` ? Also please check all my variable spelling, since I typed them manually. May I misstyped a variable name, what could lead to this warning.

Comment: Spelling seems just right. Warning message reffers to line:
"$filtruj = $rejestruj->insert();"
and in Class function to:
"public function insert($data){"
as it seems it is missing $data

Comment: ... You know, I really like to spend a lot of time to help other users. But I get quite angry if I spend around 20 minutes to write an answer, but you don't read it properly... Even in my comment I asked you, if you're calling the method like: `$rejestruj->insert($filtruj);` ... not `insert()` - `insert($filtruj);` ... simply put the `$filtruj` in the `insert(HERE THE VAR) and it will work. I wrote it in my answer... I wrote it even in my comment here... Can't really do more than to tell you 2x how to call the method.

Comment: Sorry to anger you I should have wrote whole objects how I call to Class:
"$rejestruj = new Dbinsert();  
  $filtruj = $rejestruj->regFilter();  
  var_dump($filtruj);  
  $filtruj = $rejestruj->insert();  
  $rejestruj->insert($filtruj);"

Comment: @korni Look at the bottom of my answer, I edited it and added you the code you should be using to avoid this warning message.

Comment: @korni I don't get it. Why are you doing `$filtruj = $rejestruj->insert();` ? What are you trying with this line? This line has absoloutly nothing to do there. Simply remove it and work with your second insert, thats all you need. Don't know what you're trying with this first insert call. May you want to explain, so I can correct you

Comment: Sorry I misread your explanation I thought it should first call to insert() with "$dodaj = $rejestruj->insert();" and then "$dodaj = $rejestruj->insert($filtruj);" but when I read it again I know it was my misunderstanding (yup I saw your edit) now it works fine!

Comment: @korni Great! :D Glad that I could help. And sorry I seemed pissed, just got a hard weekend behind me. :P 
Uhmm... Can I ask you where are you from? Also, may we can get in contact on skype or something else, so I could help you a bit more on the OOP theory. I could also write it down here, but I think that would lead to a endless comment-discussion and thats not really the goal of stackoverflow.

Comment: Im from Poland (some variable names or echos are in polish :P). Getting help from you would be really appreciated. My skype acc would need a dusting but I can contact you whatever way you like. :)

Comment: @korni Thats why I asked, I was really confused about the variable names. Was quite difficult to type them. So right now, when you visit my profile, you'll see my gmail adress on the description of my profile. (Quite on the top of the page). It is possible that you copy it and message me? And please notify me as soon as possible when you've copied my e-mail address, since I want to remove it from my profile.

Comment: Got it, mail sent.